# How to force "one page view mode"?

Tags: hyperref, pdf

In the first answer of [How to display cover page alone in the "two page view" mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21097/how-to-display-cover-page-alone-in-the-two-page-view-mode) a two page view mode for PDFs is realized via `\pdfcatalog{/PageLayout /TwoPageRight}`.

Do you know the command to enforce the usual "one page view mode" by this or any other command (without `hyperref` package).

I would have supposed it to be `\pdfcatalog{/PageLayout /OnePage}`, but it isn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of guessing you should read [hyperref manual](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-110003.7): `\pdfcatalog{/PageLayout /SinglePage}`.  Scrolling isn't continuous.

As Werner pointed out, if you want continuous scrolling you can use `\pdfcatalog{/PageLayout /OneColumn}`.

Comment: For continuous scrolling, use `/OneColumn`.

Comment: Thank you! I really googled a while before asking this question, and even tried `/SinglePage`. Now I realize that SumatraPDF is not reacting properly to the `pdfcatalog` commands, which confused me. With Adobe's Reader it is working.

Comment: @matheburg unfortunately not all PDF viewers honor all PDF settings.  Probably Adobe Reader is the only full PDF compliant viewer.