# How to view spreads after title page in two page view mode TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, live-preview

I've started writing my dissertation in Latex, and have been using TexStudio quite happily for a while. Now I've set up spreads along the lines of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21097/how-to-display-cover-page-alone-in-the-two-page-view-mode#answer-21109).

I'm wondering how to view the book PDF rendered in the PDF preview of TexStudio in the way it will show up in Adobe Acrobat; i.e. the first page is the title only, and the second page onwards shows the two-page spreads.

Comment: If you like how Adobe Acrobat displays your thesis, you could use it as external viewer with texstudio.

Comment: Hmm, I might try to use Sumatra instead then, because I do like to keep the 'navigate to source' of the builtin previewer, and as far as I know Acrobat does not support that