# How to display first page as a single page in a "Thesis" class

Tags: xetex, titles, thesis, report, page

I am writing a thesis and and I would like to view/see first page of my thesis as a single page in PDF and rest is Two pages.

I have seen this in Krishna Kumar template (https://gitlab.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template). But I have done so much that it is difficult for me to apply his template.

Problem - Currently, my first page is appears as two page. So, my each chapter title pages are starting from left side but it should start from right side. If I can print the first page (title page) as single page then my "chapter title pages" will start from right side.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...}` to `\end{document}`) showing what you have done. You only need to include 2 chapters (no need for any text). Have you used the `openany` class option because chapters normally start on recto (odd numbered) pages.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the comment. I find a solution from this discussion, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21097/how-to-display-cover-page-alone-in-the-two-page-view-mode/284113